# How to assign binary variable in AMPL in respect to another variable

Tags: linear-programming, ampl

I have a problem with AMPL modelling. Can you help me how to define a binary variable u that suppose to be equall to 0 when another variable x is also equall to 0 and 1 when x is different than 0?

I was trying to use logical expressions but solver that I am working with (cplex and minos) doesn't allow it.

My idea was:

```
subject to:
u || x != u && x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take `M` a 'big' constant such as `x < M` holds, and assume `x` is an integer (or `x >= 1` if `x` is continuous). You can use the two constraints:

```
 u <= x     (if x=0, then u=0)
 x <= M*u   (if x>0, then u=1)
```

with `u` a binary variable.

If now `x` is continuous and not necessarily greater than 1, you will have to adapt the constraints above (for example, the first constraint here would not be verified with `x=0.3` and `u=1`).

The general idea is that you can (in many cases) replace those logical constraints with inequalities, using the fact that if `a` and `b` are boolean variables, then the statement "`a` implies `b`" can be written as `b>=a` (if `a=1`, then `b=1`).